# Statistical Query in Yii

Tags: php, mysql, yii

My attempt at a statistical query is not working.  From a view in ModelA I am trying to query ModelB to find the total number of the attribute Number in ModelB where the status equals 'D' and AttributeB is equal to the logged in user.

The relation:

[image]

The relational query attemp:

```
'total' => array(self::STAT, 'TableB', 'TableAId', 'select'=>'SUM(Number)', 
            'condition'=>'Status="D" AND AttributeB='.Yii::app()->user->id),
```

Comment: What error do you have?

Comment: It is returning a value of zero, which it isn't in the db

Comment: `TableBId` should be actually the foreign key, which i guess in your case is `TableAId`, so try with `TableAId`

Comment: Sorry existing code in my app does use TableAId, that was a misprint here.

Answer (score 0):

When you specify the [`relations()`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveRecord#relations-detail), make sure that the 3rd parameter of any *relation definition* is the **foreign key** that relates the two tables.

In your case the foreign key that relates TableA and TableB is TableAId(column in TableB) , and not TableBId. Therefore change your *relation definition* to this:

```
'total' => array(self::STAT, 'TableB', 'TableAId', 'select'=>'SUM(Number)',
    'condition'=>'Status="D" AND AttributeB='.Yii::app()->user->id),
```

---

[The guide](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.arr#statistical-query) explains this, and more.

Comment: Sorry existing code in my app does use TableAId, that was a misprint here.  I corrected it in my question.  With the code above though the code outputs "0"

Comment: do you have sql logging enabled? is the expected sql executed?